# Can't boot windows after installing PrimeOS

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I installed prime os, I choose "yes" to make prime os grub. When makin the grub, I ejected the flash disk.

What is the right command list to enter the windows on the GRUB booting?
Currently windows can't boot because the GRUB command list was error.

Answer (score 0):

in teh windows GRUB booting menu
edit the GRUB command
from (hd0,0) t (hd0,1)
thats all